# compiling inception_client.cc without bazel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I need a simple function for my c++ program to be able to pull predictions from the tensorflow model server so I decided to user the inception client as a starting point.

I've followed the advice from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2412

I'm currently getting various compile errors such as: 
"undefined reference to tensorflow::serving::PredictRequest::_slow_mutable_model_spec()" and "undefined reference to tensorflow::serving::PredictRequest::~PredictRequest()"

Am I missing a library or something.
Is there a simpler way to make the function without the need for tensorflow in c++?